# Facebook like button is not displaying if the href has a dynamic component asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, facebook-like

I have a asp.net page with a repeater list on it containing Facebook like buttons. 
The like buttons render ok in the repeater items if the href on all the like buttons are the same in all of the items, but if I place a query string component in the href it will only show the last item in the repeater.

e.g. the URL that will render the controls properly http://www.mysite.com/asppage.aspx
but putting querystring component http://www.mysite.com/asppage.aspx?querystring=uniqueID where unique id is unique number in each repeater list item

I have followed all of the facebook guides but nothing fixed this issue 
I’m using the HTML5 version of the facebook like button

```
lblFaceBookLikeButton.Text = "<div class='fb-like' data-href='http://www.mysite.com/asppage.aspx?querystring=uniqueID '  data-send='true' data-width='450' data-show-faces='true'></div>";
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Place a & symbol at the end of the queryString fixes this issue

Comment: I am encountering this same issue. Thanks for the answer!